# What is the file format of the private key when combining with a .cer to create a .pfx using OpenSSL

Tags: openssl, private-key

I am trying to combine a .cer and a private key into a .pfx file using OpenSSL. (to use for code siging in Visual Studio)

I'm using: openssl.exe pkcs12 -export -in d:\testpfx\mycert.cer -inkey d:\testpfx\privatekey.txt -out d:\testpfx\certfile.pfx

My private key is a simple text file with the -----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----xxxxx-----END PRIVATE KEY-----. I am getting an error: unable to load private key
26188:error:0909006C:PEM routines:get_name:no start line:crypto\pem\pem_lib.c:745:Expecting: ANY PRIVATE KEY

I'm not certain where to go from here. Does anyone know the correct format of the private key file if it's a simple text field?

Comment: Have you checked the line endings on your private key file?  If you're jumping between Windows and Linux or MacOS you may find that the file has different line endings to what OpenSSL is expecting.

Comment: this is all windows. I haven't checked line endings. I cant figure out the meaning of "Expecting: ANY PRIVATE KEY"

Comment: Intensivist: PEM files can support many data types and the type is indicated by the words in the BEGIN XXX or END XXX lines. OpenSSL supports _six_ different PEM types of private keys, and many commands including `pkcs12 -export` can read _any_ of them, so the error message says 'ANY' to indicate this. Your BEGIN/END PRIVATE KEY should be okay. Note a PEM file MUST have line breaks: ----BEGIN XXX----- LINEBREAK base64 data WITH LINEBREAKS -----END XXX----- LINEBREAK. Does yours? ...

Comment: ... Since you appear to be on Windows, did you create or edit this file with a Windows program in 'unicode'? In that case it usually puts an  invisible Byte Order Mark, better known as BOM(B) because it screws up OpenSSL and some other programs.

Comment: I used Godaddy to create the csr and the private key. The private key was then saved directly to a folder and I used it without prior editing. It was saved as a txt file and I left that extension

Comment: Dave! you were right on. I used notepad++ to save with the correct UTF-8 encoding.

Answer (score 1):

dave_thompson_085 was right. The private key I saved from GoDaddy was indeed in UTF-8-BOM. The key file was saved with UTF-8 encoding and was then read successfully by OpenSSL